# How to deploy a Windows forms project with a database connection to some other machine?

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I have a small demo windows forms application, which has 2 forms.

1. enter a name in the first form, which will add the name to a table in the database. The back-end used is SQL Server 2008.
2. After successful entry in the database, the user is prompted to the second form, which is basically a demo calculator.

My question is how can I deploy this project to some other machine. Wana create a normal executable file, in the other machine.

I was able to deploy one another windows forms app, which was without a SQL database connection, by using the Setup and Deployment wizard of the VS 2008.

Also, does the other machine would have to have certain prerequisites, like presence of SQL server in it?

I googled... found some MSDN links but could not find meaningful results.

Any assistance or an external pointer to this scenario would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get connections string using `ConfigurationManager` and set connection string in app.config.
    Getting connection string from app.config example:

```
string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnStr"].ConnectionString;
```

After deploy you application you can change app.config manually or make in your app simple form for set connection string.

Comment: thank you..will try it...Editing the form to set the connection string accordingly should do the trick..thanks fr the info...

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a Setup Project to your Solution and relay on the automatic dependency detection that it brings to build an MSI setup kit for your application that would bundle any dependencies. Not sure about the SQL Server though...

Comment: hii..i ws pretty successful in creating a .msi installer by using the Setup Project, for one of my Windows app, which was without a Database connection....it worked fine in other machines too..The problem I face is what sort of steps to take in order to deploy a Windows app, which has a database connection....

Answer (score 0):

Since it needs a DB for its execution, you have to provide a sql server instance for it. This can be any of these below mentioned

1. a dedicated SQL server on the network
2. SQLServer installed on any one of the machines on the network and configured correctly for accepting connections from other machines on the network
3. SQL Server local instance installed on the second machine if the second machine is not on the network or the program is independent of the network.

AFAIK, for deployment you can copy exe (built after proper connectionstring configuration) or you can rely on setup project